# Which Graph API Version is used by spring-social-facebook

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

Which Graph API Version is used by Spring-Social-Facebook in the current stable release 1.1.0.RELEASE? I expect it's the Graph API v1.x but I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Is there allready a stable solution for the Graph API v2.x? Is it somewhere configurable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to upgrade to Spring Social Facebook 2.0.0. From https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/03/spring-social-facebook-2-0-0-m1-released:

> The primary focus of this release was to update the API binding to
>   target version 2.0 of Facebook's Graph API.

Comment: Here is the maven info in case anyone else is looking for it:  
`<dependency>  
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>  
  <artifactId>spring-social-facebook-web</artifactId>  
  <version>2.0.0.M1</version>  
</dependency>`

Answer (score 2):

Just make down in case anyone is checking Graph API level of Spring Social Facebook 2.0.3 
https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/09/spring-social-facebook-2-0-3-released

> In addition, the API binding has been adjusted to target Graph API v2.5.